# Homogeneous ODE with multiple changes of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

How to solve the homogeneous ODE

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{2tx}{t^2 - x^2}
$$

I’ve changed the variable such that $y=x/t$ and I came up with the following

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{y}{t} + \frac{2yt}{1-y^2}
$$

Everything I have tried after this result, failed. Can someone give me a hint, how to find the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Argiel: **Hint:** Here is a variant of your trick - try letting $x = v t$, so $x' = v + v' t$. Substitute those two items and then proceed.

Comment: FWIW @Moo 's substitution is good because the ODE is scale invariant under $t\rightarrow at$ and $x\rightarrow ax$ for some constant $a$. If you have an ODE which is scale invariant under $t\rightarrow at$ and $x\rightarrow a^Nx$, then a transformation $x(t)=t^Nv(t)$ will reduce it to an equidimensional equation in $t$.

Comment: If you change the independent parameter to separate the quotient on the right side, you get to $z'(s)=z(s)^2$ where $z=t+ix$, with the usual solution. This should at least serve to confirm otherwise obtained solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Answering just to remove this from the unanswered questions list: as was noted in the comments, a substitution $x(t)=tv(t)$ transforms the ODE into

$$
v+v't=\frac{2v}{1-v^2}
$$

which is equidimensional in $t$; *i.e*. it is invariant under a rescaling $t\rightarrow at$. Changing the independent variable to $t=e^{\tau}$ produces

$$
v+v'=\frac{2v}{1-v^2}
$$

where the derivative is evaluated with respect to $\tau$. This is a first-order separable ODE:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{v}-\frac{2v}{1+v^2}\right) dv&=d\tau\\
\ln\left(\frac{|v|}{1+v^2}\right)&=\tau-c_1\\
\frac{|v|}{1+v^2}&=c_1e^{\tau}
\end{align}
$$

We can remove the absolute values bars on $v$ by letting $c_1\in\mathbb{R}$. Changing variables from $\tau$ back to $t$, and from $v$ back to $x$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{v}{1+v^2}&=c_1t\\
\frac{t\cdot(vt)}{t^2+(vt)^2}&=c_1t\\
\frac{x}{t^2+x^2}&=c_1
\end{align}
$$

Solving for $x(t)$, we obtain

$$
x(t)=\frac{c_1\pm\sqrt{c_1^2-4t^2}}{2}
$$

Note that $x=0$ is also a solution to the ODE which we cannot obtain from any choice of $c_1$ in the above.